# How do physics work for ball and paddle style games like Breakout and Pong?

Tags: c#, xna

I have the following game:

[image]

I have the rectangle collisions ready with the ball and with the tiles. but my problem is when the ball hits the tiles and the bat, what angle should the ball bounce at?  How do I determine that?

Comment: This isn't explicitly an answer to the question, but check out Farseer (http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) for whatever physics calculations you may need. There's material about it here on StackOverflow and a lot more on the XNA forums.

Answer (score 4):

You should read up on physics, specifically [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28physics%29). There are lots of tutorials on [Breakout style physics](http://www.scriptedfun.com/arinoid-an-arkanoid-clone/).

Answer (score 2):

It's not that difficult, if the ball hits a vertical obstacle simply invert its x velocity, if it hits a horizontal obstacle invert its y velocity.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a built in method in the XNA Vector2 class just for this. Check out the [Vector2.Reflect method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.reflect.aspx).